# MSBuild Exclude Project when DeployOnBuild flag is set to true

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

I have the following msbuild arguments:

```
/m /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile="$(PublishProfile).pubxml"
```

I've added a project that is a shared .NET Web Application that should not be deployed, and does not need publish profiles.  However when my build agent runs, it fails because my project does not have publish profiles.

Is there a way to exclude a project or somehow work around this without having to specify individual projects to include?

Comment: Exclude it in what? You haven't provided any working code samples. If you can't help us, we can't help you.

Comment: @CJohnson this is a config question, not a code question.  If you can't help, keep your comments to yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to exclude a project or somehow work around this without having to specify individual projects to include?

AFAIK, I am afraid there is no such way or property we could exclude a project to be deployed on the Azure DevOps directly.

If you do not want to specify individual projects to include.

**As a workaround**, you could define the property `DeployOnBuild` in the projects that you want to publish, and pass a value to the property in msbuild arguments to make only this(those) project(s) can be built.

Details:

**Edited project(s) which you want to publish and added** the following property group before the Import statements in the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DeployOnBuild Condition=" '$(DeployProjOrNot)'!='' ">$(DeployProjOrNot)</DeployOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then the msbuild arguments:

```
/m /p:DeployProjOrNot=true /p:PublishProfile="$(PublishProfile).pubxml"
```

In this case, those projects will be published, and the shared .NET Web Application (should not add above Property) will not be published due to the value of the property `DeployOnBuild` is not set to be **true**.

Hope this helps.